# Rails - Use result of query as a conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that creates a new device based on the name of the device entered by the user, as well as some other data.  I want to run a query on my Devices to see if the name they entered already exists so that they may not create a device with duplicate names.  No matter how I set up a query to do the search, the method always states that the device already exists, even if it doesn't.  With out the conditional statement, the code creates devices appropriately.  Any ideas how I can work this out?

The method in Device controller:

```
def create
 if Device.where('name' => params[:name])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Cannot create device. It already exists.' }
  end
  else

 #Code that creates device

 #respond_to code

 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use model-level validation to prevent duplicate data.

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => 'already exists'

...
end
```

That way in your controller you can base decisions on the `save` method.

```
@device = params[:device]
respond_to do |format|
  if @device.save
    format.html # successful save
   else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
   end
end
```

Comment: This solution works, but I'm unable to get my app to redirect on failures.  It just goes to the rails error page stating 'Name already exists'.  Any ideas?  Do you actaully commit the save by calling it in the if statement?  In my current code, device.save! is before the if statement that checks if it save.s

Comment: I updated the answer for a typical response, which in this case is to render the `new` action and use `flash` to display the error message(s).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it always passes is because it returns a empty array and `if []` will return true. To see if a user with that name exists you could use this:

```
Device.where(:name => params[:name]).exists?
```

but you shouldn't do it like that. You should use validations:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => true
```

Check the guides for more insight about validations and how to use them:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Also see the second answer for the more detailed explanation, and stuff like this is nicely explained in this book:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-presence_validation